# Is it possible to compute the Iwahori Decomposition using the Chavalley Commutator Formulas?

Tags: nt.number-theory, lie-algebras

Ideally, I would like a constructive, algorithmic proof of this fact. I have convinced myself that it is true, but my "proof" is not pretty. I would like to know if a more attractive or intuitive proof exists, or if I am in fact wrong.

Comment: Can you explain the setting in a little more detail?   (Also, the name is "Chevalley".)